# How to retrieve subset in partitioning algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, python-3.x, partitioning

I have an array and I would like to split it two parts such that their sum is equal for example `[10, 30, 20, 50]` can be split into `[10, 40] , [20, 30]`. Both have a sum of 50. This is essentially partitioning algorithm but I'd like the retrieve the subsets not just identify whether it's partitionable. So, I went ahead and did the following:

**Update**: updated script to handle duplicates

```
from collections import Counter

def is_partitionable(a):
    possible_sums = [a[0]]
    corresponding_subsets = [[a[0]]]
    target_value = sum(a)/2
    if a[0] == target_value:
        print("yes",[a[0]],a[1:])
        return
    for x in a[1:]:
        temp_possible_sums = []
        for (ind, t) in enumerate(possible_sums):
            cursum = t + x
            if cursum < target_value:
                corresponding_subsets.append(corresponding_subsets[ind] + [x])
                temp_possible_sums.append(cursum)
            if cursum == target_value:
                one_subset = corresponding_subsets[ind] + [x]
                another_subset = list((Counter(a) - Counter(one_subset)).elements())
                print("yes", one_subset,another_subset)
                return
        possible_sums.extend(temp_possible_sums)
    print("no")
    return

is_partitionable(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

Sample Input & Output:

```
>>> is_partitionable([10,30,20,40])
yes [10, 40] [30, 20]
>>> is_partitionable([10,30,20,20])
yes [10, 30] [20, 20]
>>> is_partitionable([10,30,20,10])
no
```

I'm essentially storing the corresponding values that were added to get a value in `corresponding_subsets`. But, as the size of `a` increases, it's obvious that the `corresponding_subsets` would have way too many sub-lists (equal to the number of elements in `possible_sums`). Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , One minute please , a small bug

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , Updated!

Comment: @sasha , no there isn't , i am just doing this for myself but I'm worried about the efficiency , I think there must be a better way than storing such a huge list of lists, let's say my array size is in the order of `10^5`+

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , no there's no constraint like that, I just want to retrieve the subsets with equal sum!, no I haven't , I must be some *top-down* way to store lists so that we can only store the top-most lists and then can retrieve bottom lists which are just subsets of top-lists?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , one minute, that was due to duplicate issue

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , done. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @PruthviRaj No problem. How about this `[40, 20, 20]`? Why does this fail? Also lets delete some comments to keep this in a single page. ☺

Comment: @Ev.Kounis , Thanks again that's coz i didn't check the first value in array , I initialized `possible_values` to `a[0]` . So `[20, 20, 40]` works. One minute .... fixing, updated !

Comment: Another thing, `possible_sums` is just `a[0]` so integer but you iterate over it with `for (ind, t) in enumerate(possible_sums):`. Do you mind explaining that? I don't see the reason.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis it's because I'm keeping track of `possible_lists` with `corresponding_subsets` , i used it in the first statements of the `if` branches if you see

Comment: Change that to `print("yes",[a[0]],a[1:])` since `a[0]` is not a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it is still a hard problem, you could try the following. I assume that there are `n` elements and they are stored in the array named `arr` ( I assume 1-based indexing ). Let us make two teams `A` and `B`, such that I want to partition the elements of `arr` among teams `A` and `B` such that sum of elements in both the teams is equal. Each element of `arr` has an option of either going to team `A` or team `B`. Say if an element ( say ith element ) goes to team `A` we denote it by `-a[i]` and if it goes to team `B` we let it be `a[i]`. Thus after assigning each element to a team, if the total sum is `0` our job is done. We will create `n` sets ( they do not store duplicates ). I will work with the example `arr = {10,20,30,40}`. Follow the following steps

```
set_1 = {10,-10} # -10 if it goes to Team A and 10 if goes to B

set_2 = {30,-10,10,-30} # four options as we add -20 and 20

set_3 = {60,0,20,-40,-20,-60} # note we don't need to store duplicates

set_4 = {100,20,40,-40,60,-20,-80,0,-60,-100} # see there is a zero means our task is possible
```

Now all you have to do is backtrack from the `0` in the last set to see if the ith element `a[i]` was added as `a[i]` or as `-a[i]`, ie. whether it is added to Team `A` or `B`.

**EDIT**

The backtracking routine. So we have `n` sets from `set_1` to `set_n`. Let us make two lists `list_A` to push the elements that belong to team `A` and similarly `list_B`. We start from `set_n` , thus using a variable `current_set` initially having value `n`. Also we are focusing at element `0` in the last list, thus using a variable `current_element` initially having value `0`. Follow the approach in the code below ( I assume all sets 1 to `n` have been formed, for sake of ease I have stored them as list of list, but you should use set data structure ). Also the code below assumes a `0` is seen in the last list ie. our task is possible.

```
sets = [ [0], #see this dummy set it is important, this is set_0
              #because initially we add -arr[0] or arr[0] to 0
         [10,-10],
         [30,-10,10,-30],
         [60,0,20,-40,-20,-60],
         [100,20,40,-40,60,-20,-80,0,-60,-100]]

# my array is 1 based so ignore the zero
arr = [0,10,20,30,40]

list_A = []
list_B = []

current_element = 0
current_set = 4 # Total number of sets in this case is n=4

while current_set >= 1:
   print current_set,current_element
   for element in sets[current_set-1]:
     if element + arr[current_set] == current_element:
       list_B.append(arr[current_set])
       current_element = element
       current_set -= 1
       break
     elif element - arr[current_set] == current_element:
       list_A.append(arr[current_set])
       current_element = element
       current_set -= 1
       break


print list_A,list_B
```

Comment: the way you search for feasibility is beautiful (+1) but i am not sure if the backtracking is that easy. But for each element of the final set there exists a let's say list that looks like this: `[1, -1, -1, 1]` with the numbers denoting where each element went. from then on, recreating the partitions is trivial.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Will make an edit shortly to include the backtracking routine.

Comment: Nice solution , waiting for the backtracking routine

Comment: @PruthviRaj I added the routine. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @sasha ,Thanks for idea and help, I rearranged the array to `[0,10,20,40,30]` and it isn't working

Comment: @PruthviRaj You will have to change the sets too.

Comment: @PruthviRaj because the sets are generated in accordance to the array.

Comment: @sasha I did! , please check this gist to verify i'm doing it right: [partitioning-test.py](https://gist.github.com/devpruthvi/6edba7a693efbde47dfb87476c3dc54c)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123465/discussion-between-sasha-and-pruthvi-raj).

Comment: I hope thinks are sorted now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of @sasha's algo on the feasibility.

```
def my_part(my_list):
    item = my_list.pop()
    balance = []
    temp = [item, -item]
    while len(my_list) != 0:
        new_player = my_list.pop()
        for i, items in enumerate(temp):
            balance.append(items + new_player)
            balance.append(items - new_player)
        temp = balance[:]
    balance = set(balance)
    if 0 in balance:
        return 'YES'
    else:
        return 'NO'
```

I am working on the backtracking too.